# Python: Best way to automate account logins for website and extract information for each sign-in attempt?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, screen-scraping

I was wondering if anyone could kindly recommend the best procedure for doing this in Python 3.5:

I have 250 sets of usernames and passwords
I have to login to a particular website for each account (so 250 times) and grab their account information

I've seen examples but usually for only 1 sign-in attempt. But what about for multiple logins?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# read accounts information from spreadsheet
data = pd.read_csv("HWIN Accounts.csv")
data.dropna()

# Parameters to be called
url = 'https://www.hwin.ca/hwin/login.jsp'
USERNAME = data['Username']
PASSWORD = data['Password']
data = []
data2 = []

# Find Outstanding Payments Due on Payment Tab
def find_payment(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find("td", {"class": "success"}, text=True)
    data2.append(table.text)

# Find Account Status
def find_account_status(htmls):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
    table = soup.find('table', border="0", cellpadding="2")
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

# Sign into HWIN looping through each individual account
for i in range(len(USERNAME)):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
# Input Login information into form
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("userName")
    username.send_keys(USERNAME[i])
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.send_keys(PASSWORD[i])
    form = browser.find_element_by_name("imageField")
    form.submit()
# Navigate to Account Status Tab
    browser.find_element_by_link_text("Account status").click()
# Extract Account Status Tab
    htmls = browser.page_source
    find_account_status(htmls)
# Navigate to Payments Tab
    browser.find_element_by_name("payments").click()
# Extract Payment data
    html = browser.page_source
    find_payment(html)
# Close Browser
    browser.quit()

print(data)
print(data2)
```

Comment: how about a `for` loop?

Comment: besides the `for`, your script should, within each iteration, properly log-on, scrape the data, and then log-off. Very likely there will be a UI element for this that can be scripted.

Comment: Is there a specific issue you are having a hard time wrapping your head around or that you can't get this to work?  Are you having trouble extracting the username and password data, are you having problems with logout?  Is your for-loop timing out?

Comment: So I worked on some code and posted it in my original post. The part I'm confused about is how to differentiate the output between the different accounts.